# How to Change InsetDrawable Inset value after creation

Tags: android, drawable, android-drawable

I have an `InsetDrawable` defined, and I would just like to be able to adjust the value of the inset at runtime, without re-assigning another drawable.

Is this possible?, or is the only way is to re-create the InsetDrawable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not possible, because the API for that is not public.
I had the same problem as you did, but in my case I had to animate the insets, so recreating the drawable was a quite costly option.

In the end I copied the source code of InsetDrawable, and added a method for changing the inset.

You can check it out [here](https://gist.github.com/dzolnai/5c1f763ef605e40909ee). Use the method `setInsets()` for changing the insets.