# Android Setting material button top and bottom inset programmatically (Java)

Tags: android, button, material-components-android

I created a material button programmatically and I wanted it in the bottom of screen, which is like completly fill the bottom but the problem with it is that there is a default bottom inset makes notable bottom blank space.

In order to remove inset of material button in XML is easy by simply using

android:insetLeft
android:insetRight
android:insetTop
android:insetBottom

But my question is how to set the inset value programmatically.

I found below link is very useful to get to know about material button
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialButton.md

Answer (score 2):

The support for programmatically setting top and bottom inset has been implemented in [material-components-1.3.0-alpha03](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases/tag/1.3.0-alpha03)

In Kotlin you can do:

```
val materialButton = MaterialButton(ctx)
materialButton.insetTop = 0
materialButton.insetBottom = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I also struggled to find a solution. Found it. You need create a style for the button with no insets and define it in the `materialButtonOutlinedStyle` attr of your app theme. Do not forget to specify such attr in your `MaterialButton` ctor. Like this:

**styles.xml:**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents" >
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    < ... />
    <!-- The following defines the OutlinedButton style with your custom attrs -->
    <item name="materialButtonOutlinedStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton.NoInsets</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton.NoInsets"
    parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton" >
    <!-- Here you can customize the drawable insets! -->
    <item name="android:insetTop">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:insetBottom">0dp</item>
</style>
```

**Activity/code/whatever in Java:**

```
private void addButtons() {
    MaterialButtonToggleGroup buttonGroup = findViewById(R.id.preference_selection_button_group);
    final ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );

    final int n = mEntries.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        buttonGroup.addView(createChoiceButton(i, mEntries[i]), i, lp);
}

private View createChoiceButton(int index, CharSequence entry) {
    final MaterialButton button = new MaterialButton(
            getContext(), 
            null, 
            R.attr.materialButtonOutlinedStyle /** which points to your new OutlinedButton theme **/);
    button.setId(index);
    button.setText(entry);
    return button;
}
```

**Layout:**

```
<parentLayout ...>

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
        android:id="@+id/preference_selection_button_group"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:singleSelection="true"
        app:selectionRequired="true" />

</parentLayout>
```

This code was used in a VERTICAL `MaterialButtonToggleGroup` resulting like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, there is no public method to set insets in MaterialButton source:

https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButtonHelper.java

So, you need to copy source and add something like setInsets() method.
Check this link below, it is a similar problem as yours:
[How to Change InsetDrawable Inset value after creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34976766/how-to-change-insetdrawable-inset-value-after-creation)